# Bind to nested element's function in Polymer.js

Tags: javascript

I am using Polymer.js, and I am creating an input element with a dropdown suggestions list (like google's search bar).

Basically, I have a core-input, and a core-dropdown, containing a core-menu. I have added two core-a11y-keys to observe arrow keys pressed on the core-input, in order to move the selected item in the core-menu.

I am trying to bind the core-a11y-keys' "on-keys-pressed" event directly to core-menu's selectNext(), and selectPrevious(), but I can't get it to work.

```
<template>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="suggest-input.css">
<div class="suggest-input-wrapper">
  <paper-shadow layout start-justified horizontal center id="feedSearchInput" class="input-shadow">
    <input id="searchInput" is="core-input" on-input="{{searchChanged}}" flex placeholder="{{placeholder}}">        
    <paper-icon-button icon="search" class="feed-search-icon"></paper-icon-button>
    <core-dropdown autoFocusDisabled id="suggestionsDropDown" class="suggestions-dropdown">
      <core-menu class="suggestions-menu" id="suggestionsMenu">
        <template repeat="{{suggestion in suggestionList}}">
          <paper-item class="suggestion-item">
            <template if="{{suggestion.icon}}">
              <core-icon src="{{suggestion.icon}}"></core-icon>
            </template>
            <template if="{{!suggestion.icon}}">
              <core-icon icon="search"></core-icon>
            </template>
            <h5>{{suggestion.caption}}</h5>
          </paper-item>
        </template>
      </core-menu>
    </core-dropdown>
  </paper-shadow>
</div>
```

---

```
// First Trial 
<core-a11y-keys target="{{searchInput}}" keys="down" on-keys-pressed="{{suggestionsMenu.selectNext}}"></core-a11y-keys>
<core-a11y-keys target="{{searchInput}}" keys="up" on-keys-pressed="{{suggestionsMenu.selectPrevious}}"></core-a11y-keys>
```

---

```
// Second Trial 
<core-a11y-keys target="{{searchInput}}" keys="down" on-keys-pressed="{{$.suggestionsMenu.selectNext}}"></core-a11y-keys>
<core-a11y-keys target="{{searchInput}}" keys="up" on-keys-pressed="{{$.suggestionsMenu.selectPrevious}}"></core-a11y-keys>
```

---

```
// Third Trial 
<core-a11y-keys target="{{searchInput}}" keys="down" on-keys-pressed="{{this.$.suggestionsMenu.selectNext}}"></core-a11y-keys>
<core-a11y-keys target="{{searchInput}}" keys="up" on-keys-pressed="{{this.$.suggestionsMenu.selectPrevious}}"></core-a11y-keys>
```

---

I know I can use custom event handlers, and than call selectNext() and selectedPrevious(), but knowing if it can be done, and how, could help in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
target="{{$.searchInput}}"
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. The targeted element is working fine, so it isn't a problem with the target attribute.